# Where can I check the window width (for mobile header) in Angular?

Tags: angular, single-page-application, angular5

I want to display two different headers (one for PC and one for mobile) in an Angular SPA depending on the screen size.

My first question is: should I put the mobile header in a seperate component or as different CSS using the @media tag?

My second question is: where should I check the screenwidth and tell Angular to load a different component or different CSS depending on the screen width? I.e. in the app.component.html (using ng-if), in the app.component.ts, in the css...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a function, if the width of the component's DOM element is changed? (Angular4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391095/how-to-call-a-function-if-the-width-of-the-components-dom-element-is-changed)

Comment: @estus My question is fairly different though.

Comment: It's same case. You need to watch for width, you subscribe to `resize` event. As you can see, the answer is similar too, except that HostListener is used instead of `window` because it's idiomatic. CSS @media won't help you because you need to get width changes as variable.

Comment: @estus I get what you're saying but why will @ media not work? I am currently using @ media and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Because you also need *to load a different component or different CSS depending on the screen width*, and this cannot be handled with @media, but `width` component property can handle both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are purely interested in altering the view using CSS on a small scale I would just use [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
    .element {
        display: none
    }
}
```

If you are doing this on a large scale you might want to look into some responsive frameworks, specifically [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/)

Otherwise, if you want to load different components into the view depending on screensize, you would need to move beyond CSS and put the logic that checks screen size, into a `Service` that Angular can watch and react to as necessary.

**screen-size.service.ts**

```js
// Initialize the Screen Size Behavior Subject
private ScreenSize$: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(window.innerWidth);
// Convert the Screen Size Behavior Subject into an Observable
ScreenSize: Observable<number> = this.ScreenSize$.asObservable();

constructor() {
    // Initialize the Event Listener for the Resizing of the Window
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        // Update the Screen Size Behavior Subject
        this.updateScreenSize(window.innerWidth);
    })
    // Classify Screen Size
    this.classifyScreenSize();
}

// Update the Screen Size Behavior Subject
private updateScreenSize(ScreenSize: number): void {
    this.ScreenSize$.next(ScreenSize);
}
```

By using the above code in a service you can subscribe to the ScreenSize `Observable` throughout your app and your components can respond accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, that clears up a lot. Is it smart to devide the header and mobile header into different components?

Comment: It really depends on what they're doing. Basic UX  guidelines would dictate that both should look and feel the same, along with containing "generally" the same functionality. If it were me I wouldn't separate them, but rather adapt the one to adjust to different screen sizes.

Comment: Accessing `window` directly will provide certain complications. It isn't compatible with SSR and can provlde memory leaks.

Comment: @estus I had no idea it would create memory leaks, good to know. Can you explain how? Also why "For Starters"? What else is wrong?

Comment: Event listener is never unsubscribed. Not a big problem if it's module provider (will cause be memory leaks in tests, but this isn't [the biggest problem](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13725) we're currently having). Memory will leak if the service is instantiated not globally but by components - the service is destroyed but the listener is not unsubscribed. Another problem is SSR. There's no `window` on server side. `HostListener` is idiomatic solution, as suggested in dupe question, because it lets the framework to handle these issues.